# Suppose $X$ is a connected subset of $M$. Is $Int(X)$ necessarily connected?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, connectedness

Suppose $X$ is a connected subset of $M$. Is $Int(X)$ necessarily connected?

I am thinking yes since $Int(X)$ is always open, this would imply M =Int(X).

Answer (score 4):

Let $X=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:(x-1)^2+y^2\le 1\}\cup\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:(x+1)^2+y^2\le1\}$.  That is the closed disks with centers at $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ and with radii of $1$.  $\operatorname{Int}X$ are the two open disks which are disjoint. Hence $\operatorname{Int} X$ is not connected.

Comment: Wait I don't see how int(X) is the Union of the two open circles. You defined X to be the set of points around the circle with center (1,0)

Comment: @MichaelCera $X$ is the union of the closed disk with center $(1,0)$ and radius $1$ with the closed disk with center $(-1,0)$ and radius $1$.

Comment: So you say X is the set of all points in the infinity like graph that is fork when taking the union of both circles?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following symbol as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$: $$\prod$$

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this Dustan.

Comment: Presume the line across the top is $1$-dimensional, so it has no interior, and that the bars on the right and left have nonempty interior. Then the interior can be disconnected into two pieces by a line down the middle.

Comment: Unconventional, but I like it.

Comment: I was looking for a filled in infinity symbol like Tim's answer, but this works too. A little visualization never hurts.